# Class Constructor - No Instance of Constructor

Tags: c++, class

I am learning to use composition. A Student class with Project class as a data member. The error is regarding this code: sproject(p) in Student.cpp.

Error message:

> ```
> char p
>
> no instance of constructor "Project::Project" matched the argument list
> ```

**Student.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "Project.h"
#include "Date.h"

class Student
{
public:
    Student(int, char, int, int, int, char);
    void setStudent(int, char, int, int, int, char);
    ~Student();
private:
    int ID;
    char name;
    Date DOB;
    Project sproject;
};
```

**Student.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include "Project.h"

Student::Student(int i, char s, int d, int m, int y, char p)
    : DOB(d, m, y), 
    sproject(p)
{
    setStudent(i, s, d, m, y, p);
}

void Student::setStudent(int number, char stN, int da, int mo, int ye, char pr)
{
    ID = number;
    name = stN;
    DOB = (da, mo, ye);
    sproject = pr;


}

Student::~Student()
{
}
```

**Project.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "Supervisor.h"
#include "Date.h"

class Project
{
public:
    Project(char, int, int, int, char);
    void setProject(char, int, int, int, char);
    ~Project();
private:
    char pname;
    Date startDate;
    Supervisor supervisor;
};
```

**Project.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Project.h"
#include "Supervisor.h"
#include "Date.h"

Project::Project(char projectName, int sDay, int sMonth, int sYear, char supervisorName)
    : Date(sDay, sMonth, sYear), 
    : Supervisor(supervisorName)
{
    setProject(projectName, sDay, sMonth, sYear, supervisorName);
}

void Project::setProject(char pN, int d, int m, int y, char sN)
{
    pname = pN;
    startDate = (d, m, y);
    supervisor = sN;
}

Project::~Project()
{
}
```

I do not understand this error message. Any ideas where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your student has a member variable

```
Project sproject;
```

You are trying to construct it with

```
sproject(p)   // where p is a char
```

Therefore it is looking for a constructor with a signature

```
Project(char)
```

but obviously that does not exist, you only have a constructor with this signature

```
Project(char, int, int, int, char);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `project.h` file defines only one constructor for the `Project` class, and that constructor requires five arguments, `(char, int, int, int, char)`.

The line that gets the error appears to be trying to call a constructor that takes only one argument `(char)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Project constructor takes a char, 3 ints and a char. In your construction of Student, you only pass a single char to you Project :) All params must be met when constructing